# Ensure that the content of one element is equal to a key (keyref for content)

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have two lists of different elements (`ruleRef` and `rule`) in the same XML file.
I'd like to make sure that the content of `ruleRef` equals the name of any `rule`.

In my XSD I already have a `xs:key` restriction like such:

```
<xs:key name="ruleName">
  <xs:selector xpath="rules/rule"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
</xs:key>
```

I've also used this key before to validate the attribute of another element like such:

```
<xs:keyref name="differentRuleRef" refer="ruleName">
  <xs:selector xpath="rules/rule/differentRuleRef"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@referencedRule"/>
</xs:keyref>
```

Now I'd like to validate the actual content of an element instead of an attribute.
E.g. in the following XML the second `<ruleRef>` element should be invalid:

```xml
<root>
  <rules>
    <rule name="rule1"/>
    <rule name="rule2"/>
  </rules>
  <ruleRefs>
    <ruleRef>rule1</ruleRef>
    <ruleRef>nonExistantRule</ruleRef> <!-- invalid -->
  </ruleRefs>
</root>
```

I've tried `text()` and `data(.)` before, but both of them are not valid in the XPath-subset.
I've also tried `.` and `ruleRef`, but they didn't seem to validate anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.` for the `xs:field` in your `xs:keyref` should be working, I rather suspect a mistatch in the XPath for the `xs:selector`.

On the `<root>` element, defining the following in the schema is working on the XML sample you provided:

```
<xs:element name="root" type="root">
    <xs:key name="ruleName">
        <xs:selector xpath="rules/rule"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref refer="ruleName" name="differentRuleRef">
        <xs:selector xpath="ruleRefs/ruleRef"/>
        <xs:field xpath="."/>
    </xs:keyref>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="root">
   <!-- define root content type here ...-->
</xs:complexType>
```

Another approach (somewhat simpler) could be to use the ID / IDREF mechanism, and you can get rid of the `xs:key` / `xs:keyref` definition in your shema, and modify the definition of rules and ruleRefs :

```
   <xs:element name="rule" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:ID" />
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>

   <xs:element name="ruleRef" type="xs:IDREF" maxOccurs="unbounded">
   </xs:element>
```

This will constraint the rule names to be unique.

Comment: Apparently I had a different mistake when I used `.`, because now I used it and it immediately worked… Well thank you anyways :)